# Expo - ReactNative - AuthSession with Google does not work in standalone if responseType: "id_token"

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo, google-authentication

I am trying to authorise Google SignIn by using Google from `expo-auth-session/providers/google";`.

I need to get a specific response type which is `id_token`. In expo it works, Google returns all I need, but in Standalone, Google throws an error that such response type is unsupported. If I omit this property, all works fine, but I don't get an id_token, so it does not help me.

I wanted to know is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1 - Add `responseType: 'id_token'` in `useAuthRequest`

```
const [requestIdToken, responseIdToken, promptAsyncIdToken] =
    Google.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: 'id_token',
      androidClientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_ANDROID,
      iosClientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_IOS,
      expoClientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_WEB_EXPO,
      scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
   })
```

Alternative 2 - Try changing your `useAuthRequest` by `useIdTokenAuthRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `useAuthRequest` for `useIdTokenAuthRequest worked perfectly for me.

In the docs they only show `useIdTokenAuthRequest` for use with firebase, but it works with all the same arguments as the normal `useAuthRequest` method